# Alignment Inside a WPF MenuItem

Tags: c#, wpf, text, menu, alignment

In my application I have a `Menu` object where each `MenuItem` has another `MenuItem`, both of them get their data from property defined in the VM. Then I set up a `Command` with a `MultiValueConverter` and everything works as intended.

My issues lie on the `Menu` rendering: as you can see from the attached screenshot, the `TextBlocks` containing the numeric data aren't stretched for the full width of the `Menu` itself, making really hard to trigger the `LeftClick` interaction. I would like to make each `TextBlock` (and if possible each `Header` too) to fill the entire menu, but even if I put `HorizontalAlignment` and `HorizontalContentAlignment` as `Stretched` the appearance does not change.

[image: The rendered and populated Menu. The TextBlocks have the yellow background, while the Headers have the red one.]

Besides that, I wonder how to eliminate the empty column on the left of each `MenuItem`, but I don't understand where they are defined.

Here is the relevant XAML:

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="SynergyTemplate">
            <Menu
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                Visibility="{Binding Path=SynergySelectionActive, Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=VM}, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BoolToVisConverter}}">
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=RenderValue.CurrentItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TabledValues}">
                    <MenuItem.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </MenuItem.ItemsPanel>
                    <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Menu>
                                <MenuItem
                                    x:Name="SynergyMenuItem"
                                    Background="Red"
                                    Header="{Binding Path=Render}"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SynergyPanelParameters, Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=VM}, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=MachineToDiametersConverter}}">
                                    <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock
                                                x:Name="SynergyDiameterText"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                Background="Yellow"
                                                Text="{Binding .}">
                                                <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                                                    <MouseBinding Command="{Binding Path=UpdateSynergyCommand, Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=VM}}" Gesture="LeftClick">
                                                        <MouseBinding.CommandParameter>
                                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=StdMultiConverter}">
                                                                <Binding ElementName="SynergyMenuItem" Path="DataContext" />
                                                                <!--  Datacontext here is the source list item, exactly what I need to process the command -->
                                                                <Binding ElementName="SynergyDiameterText" Path="Text" />
                                                            </MultiBinding>
                                                        </MouseBinding.CommandParameter>
                                                    </MouseBinding>
                                                </TextBlock.InputBindings>
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                                </MenuItem>
                            </Menu>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </DataTemplate>
```

So, my questions are:

1. How can I make `TextBlock` and `Header` to "fill" the entire `MenuItem`?
2. How can I hide/remove the empty column on the left of each menu?

Comment: You need to define a custom `ControlTemplate` for the `MenuItem`.